# devexpress coderush and XAML

Tags: devexpress, coderush

this question is targeted towards coderush users.
I am trying to recover from a bad surgery and bought an online tutorial on how to convert old wpf apps to the new modern style(metro).

The instructor on video has Resharper installed, where I have coderush. In resharper everything seems to be done automatically. Namespaces in xaml are entered by R#, colors are shown not by name but by color.
In my old coderush nothing was working.

So i thought my old expired version is finally outdated. I had version 12. Devexpress is very generous to offer a 30 day trial! so i updated!
 **But alas, the same!**

Its very annoying, especially trying to pick a color and instead seeing the real color you see a few dozen names..

So, are there any settings i can fiddle with??? to make this tool more assisting???

Comment: AFAIK, xaml-features are available with CodeRush since 13.1 version:
https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2013/06/07/new-xaml-features-in-coderush-13-1-for-visual-studio.aspx
Please check that you are using the latest one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine in XAML. The color picker in CodeRush supports all supported languages.

You have to click the color swatch which appears underneath the color name.

[image]